# Django finding which field matched in a multiple OR query

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys

I've got a couple models which are set up something like this:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
  baz = models.CharField()

class Foo(models.Model):
  bar1 = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
  bar2 = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
  bar3 = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
```

And elsewhere in the code, I end up with an instance of Bar, and need to find the Foo it is attached to in some capacity. Right now I came up with doing a multiple OR query using Q, something like this:

```
foo_inst = Foo.objects.get(Q(bar1=bar_inst) | Q(bar2=bar_inst) | Q(bar3=bar_inst))
```

What I need to figure out is, which of the 3 cases actually hit, at least the name of the member (bar1, bar2, or bar3). Is there a good way to do this? Is there a better way to structure the query to glean that information?

Comment: What's the difference between `bar1`, `bar2`, `bar3`?

Comment: They are most likely pointing to different Bar instances!

Comment: Sorry yes, bar1, bar2, and bar3 are all separate Bar instances. A Foo will have 0-3 different Bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    Foo.objects.get(bar1=bar_inst)
    print 'bar1'
except Foo.DoesNotExist:
    try:
        Foo.objects.get(bar2=bar_inst)
        print 'bar2'
    except Foo.DoesNotExist:
        try:
           Foo.objects.get(bar3=bar_inst)
           print 'bar3'
        except Foo.DoesNotExist:
           print 'nothing found'
```

Also consider adding [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to all the bar fields of your model.

Comment: I suppose this works, it's a bit db intensive but perhaps my design is just the problem...in any event, the use case for the moment is pretty low volume so this will probably work unless something better gets suggested

Answer (score 0):

You could change things up and use a `ChoiceField`?

```
BAR_VERSIONS = (
    ('Bar 1', 'bar1'),
    ('Bar 2', 'bar2'),
    ('Bar 3', 'bar3'),
)


class Bar(models.Model):
  baz = models.CharField()

class Foo(models.Model):
  bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
  bar_version = models.ChoiceField(choices=BAR_VERSIONS)
```

Then:

```
try:
    foo_instance = Foo.objects.get(bar=bar_instance)
except Foo.DoesNotExist:
    # Handle Exception
    pass
else:
    print(foo_instance.bar_version)
```

**UPDATE:**
From your comment, as the idea is to have none or all `bar`s set you could still use this approach but use a `ManyToManyField` with the `through` parameter.  This would make it nice and extendible in the future if you wanted to add `bar4` - `barn` rather than extending your try-except waterfall.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

```
class Bar(models.Model):
  baz = models.CharField()

class Foo(models.Model):
  bars = models.ManyToManyField(bar, through='FooBars')

class FooBars(models.Model):
  foor = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
  bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
  bar_version = models.ChoiceField(choices=BAR_VERSIONS)
```

Comment: Well choices is out, as there are going to be probably thousands of Bars. But the "through" setup might work, I'll give it a shot